# Confusion regarding countvectorizer

Tags: nlp, countvectorizer

why do I have to apply Countvectorizer on a smaller sample and then make the data frame? why can't I apply a count vectorizer to a large sample and create a data frame out of it?

here is my code :=
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()

X = cv.fit_transform(data['Pros_clean_lemma'])
print(X.shape)

output ; (128734, 26537)